# В Laravel routes, перед callback функцией используется static, для чего оно нужно?

Tags: php, laravel

В коде проекта в Laravel routes файле есть код  в котором используется не известная мне конструкция, а именно перед callback функцией  используется static, для чего это сделанно ?

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], static function () {
   Route::group(['namespace' => 'v1', 'prefix' => 'v1'], static function () {
      Route::get('/rates', 'RatesController');
      Route::post('/convert', 'ConvertController');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Это ограничивает доступ внутри функции к $this - объекту класса, в методах которого она создана.

Подробнее https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static

Этот код в Laravel не имеет контекста класса, поэтому использование анонимной функции без static бессмысленно.

Если пользуетесь PhpStorm, плагин https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended- будет предлагать вам использовать static, если нет обращения к $this. Возможно улучшение производительности.

Comment: Не знаю хорошая ли  практика ставить static перед анонимной функцией  во всяком случае  в  коде laravel  8,  routes/web.php    без  static ов